# Iterate through each rows of a column and perform operation

Tags: python

I have my data -

```
data = [['abc - a', 'A'], ['def - b', 'B'], ['ghi - c', 'C'], ['jkl - d', 'D']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['names', 'category'])
df
names   category
abc - a   A
def - b   B
ghi - c   C
jkl - d   D
```

What I want as my output is -

```
names     division    category
    abc      a          A
    def      b          B
    ghi      c          C
    jkl      d          D
```

There are a lot of methods to perform this, but I want to perform this with this logic -

iterate through each rows of column-names, and store each value in 'st1' and then ->

```
first, middle, last = st1.partition(' - ')
df['names'] = first
df['division'] = last
```

and also assigning it to dataframe one by one, please help me to get my desired output in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm testing out github copilot to see how it can solve stackoverflow issues.

```
# Solution 1
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [['abc - a', 'A'], ['def - b', 'B'], ['ghi - c', 'C'], ['jkl - d', 'D']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['names', 'category'])


# Iterate through each rows of column-names, and store each value in 'st1' and then ->
# first, middle, last = st1.partition(' - ')
# df['names'] = first
# df['division'] = last
# and also assigning it to dataframe one by one, please help me to get my desired output in python.


for index, row in df.iterrows():
    st1 = row['names']
    first, middle, last = st1.partition(' - ')
    df.loc[index, 'names'] = first
    df.loc[index, 'division'] = last

# Explain what is df.loc
# df.loc[row index, column index]
# df.loc[0, 'names'] = first
# df.loc[0, 'division'] = last

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  names category division
0   abc        A        a
1   def        B        b
2   ghi        C        c
3   jkl        D        d
```

Comment: Wait, that should be illegal. Instead of solving the problem, you are just asking Github Copilot to solve............ Just kidding but it's worth a thought.

Answer (score 2):

You could just do it like:

```
df[['names','division']] = df.names.str.split(' - ',expand=True)
```

Comment: yes i knew this, but i need to insert for loop

Answer (score 1):

Create the dataframe as you did before, then iterate over all rows of names and categories and split the names through `-`s and append them to a new dataset which is then converted into another DataFrame like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['abc - a', 'A'], ['def - b', 'B'], ['ghi - c', 'C'], ['jkl - d', 'D']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['names', 'category'])

newdata = []
for names, category in zip(df.names, df.category):
    name, division = names.split("-")
    newdata.append([name.strip(), division.strip(), category])

new_df = pd.DataFrame(newdata, columns = ['names', 'division', 'category'])
```

`print`ing the new dataframe results in:

```
>>> new_df
  names division category
0   abc        a        A
1   def        b        B
2   ghi        c        C
3   jkl        d        D
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to iterate through each of the rows in your `DataFrame` and work with them individually, you'll need to use some NumPy to get your work done. Since you want to split the rows, `.partition()` works similarly to `.split()` in Pandas, but not in NumPy.

Here are the packages you'll need:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

Before you can iterate through your rows, you'll need to use `.insert()` to create a new column named "division" (I use `np.nan` as a place filler, but you can use any value you want:

```
df.insert(1, 'division', np.nan)
```

Now you can iterate through the rows using Pandas'  `iterrows()` method.

```
# index returns the index number, row returns a tuple of the row values
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    
    # convert row values from a tuple to a row
    row = list(row)
    
    # remove 'np.nan' value from the column we created above
    row.pop(1)
    
    # split value from the 'names' column; creates values for 'names' and 'division' columns
    new_row = row[0].split(' - ')
    
    # append the value from the 'category' column
    new_row = np.append(new_row, row[1])
    
    # save the new row to the DataFrame
    df.iloc[index] = new_row
```

This is the output:

```
|    | names   | division   | category   |
|---:|:--------|:-----------|:-----------|
|  0 | abc     | a          | A          |
|  1 | def     | b          | B          |
|  2 | ghi     | c          | C          |
|  3 | jkl     | d          | D          |
```